# How to get rid of Christmas Animation from mobile screen

Tags: go-launcher-ex

I am seeing a Christmas animation on my mobile screen from 25th Dec 2012. I have no idea how did it come to my mobile. Because I rarely use internet on my mobile. And I used Internet last time at least 2-3 months before.

It automatically appears after some mins and eats my battery. I have checked all running and installed application. But none of them giving me any clue about this animation.

I am doubtful that this is the animation from Go launcher or Go SMS. but not confirmed.

I also have scanned my mob for spyware and antivirus. But nothing found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously mentioned it's from Go Launcher.  There is, however a setting to disable it.
Go to Preferences and there should be an option to disable the Christmas animation.  I can no longer find it in mine but I do know it was there when the animation was appearing.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the club -- it's from the launcher, I've got that one as well since about that time. As GoLauncher also started spamming my notification area, I used LBE to forbid it going to the network, which worked fine -- but the XMas stuff stuck since then.

So, common issue: GoLauncher not going to the net (I forbid it, and you don't have network connection often). Solution: Enable network once again, update the GoLauncher. At least here, Santa seems to be gone.

Comment: Thanks @Izzy. let me try. However, I have uninstalled Go Keyboard. Now waiting whether Santa appears again.

Comment: Maybe in 11 months? XD Good luck. However, as you started with a separate task (uninstall GoKeyboard), you will now never know which really was the cause. Maybe it would have simply gone away with the next internet connection (oh, XMas over?) -- though I cannot understand why a dev wouldn't use the system clock for the date...

Comment: Nothing happened after installing Go Keyboard. Finally I found an option in Go Launcher settings where I can off Christmas effect.

Comment: Good to know in case of Easter. For me, as said, it was enough to update to the latest version and then cut it off the net again (to avoid those notifications, which I found *no* switch for yet).